# SQL Server - create or insert table with result from a 'print @variable'

Tags: sql-server

I made this function that allows me to split cells in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxId INT = 8000, @Hashtag nVarchar(max) =''

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN

SELECT @Hashtag = @Hashtag + ' ' + Item FROM dbo.Split(' ', (SELECT
Hashtags_in_Tweet FROM TwitterSentiment WHERE Tweet_ID = @LoopCounter) );

    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1 
END

print @Hashtag
```

I used this code for the dbo.Split, which I got from another question posted here a while ago:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep VARCHAR(32), @s VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Item
    FROM (SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'& ','&amp; '),'<','&lt;'), @sep, '</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as valxml) x
    CROSS APPLY x.valxml.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
)
```

So when I have a row in column Hashtags_in_Tweet with "Cheese party fun", it results into

> Cheese
>
> Party
>
> Fun

Now I want these to be inserted in a table Hashs (int IDENTITY(1,1), varchar(800) ) I have created. I tried it with follwing script:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxId INT = 100, @Hashtag nVarchar(max) = ''

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN

SELECT @Hashtag = @Hashtag + ' ' + Item FROM dbo.Split(' ', (SELECT    
Hashtags_in_Tweet FROM TwitterSentiment WHERE Tweet_ID = @LoopCounter) );

    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1

END

insert INTO Hashs
Values ( @Hashtag )
```

But that just puts them in one row:

```
ID | Hashtag
1  | Cheese Party fun
```

While I actually wanted:

```
ID | Hashtag
1  | Cheese 
2  | Party 
3  | Fun
```

Any ways to fix this?

Comment: please add the code for `dbo.Split` as well

Comment: @ughai I have added it

Comment: Storing comma-separated values in a field *is* a very bad design. Had you created a separate table you wouldn't have any problems. Anyway, *the code explicitly* creates a single line. If you didn't want that, simply use `INSERT ... FROM dbo.Split ...`, *and* remove all loops. `WHERE Tweet_ID<=100` will return all the required rows . Was this code copied from somewhere?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Only de dbo.split function was copied from a post on this site. The rest was made by myself. But Juliens answer gave me what I searched so I'll use that instead of what I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of them at once like this:

```
SELECT ID, Item
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Item)
FROM TwitterSentiment 
Cross Apply dbo.Split(' ', Hashtags_in_Tweet)
Where Tweet_ID <= @MaxId
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job in SQL server. Is it however, also possibile in SSIS? i tried it with an execute SQL script, but that saw dbo.Split as an invalid object. Or should I make a new question for this?

Comment: You should probably create a new question. In SSIS, if you run this query on the same database, the function Split should be present and it should work. Are you should you are connected to the right server and database?